# Question about of "Substituting types" from dart documentation

Tags: dart

Reading the ["Substituting types"](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart#substituting-types) section from **"The Dart type system"** I don't understand why I get the error from assigning from one level above from hierarchy.

```
class Animal { }
class Cat extends Animal { }
class MaineCoon extends Cat { }
```

`Animal c = Cat();` works to the compiler, but `MaineCoon c = Cat();` get incorrect constructor error.

I don't understand why `MaineCoon` couldn't be cast to `Cat`, but `Animal` can cast
 `Cat` or even `Animal c = MaineCoon();` still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer (see source code below)

```
void main() {
  Animal animal = Cat();
  print(animal.animalName);
  MaineCoon maineCoon = Cat();
  // Opps!!! The "Cat" does not declares "maineCoonName".
  print(maineCoon.maineCoonName);
}

class Animal {
  String animalName = 'animal';
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  String catName = 'cat';
}

class MaineCoon extends Cat {
  String maineCoonName = 'maineCoonName';
}
```

How do you imagine accessing `maineCoonName` from instance `Cat` if `Cat` did not declare a member `maineCoonName`?

P.S.
Even if this member (I mean `maineCoonName`) is not declared, this does not mean that a similar member will not be added in the future, which, in principle, will break the entire program.